# How can I select the second copy of a text in a TMemo

Tags: delphi, tmemo

I have a `TMemo` with text inside it, for example:

```
Text1
Hello World!
Sky
Text123
```

I use a simple function to select the first time a text was found

```
Memo1.SelStart := Pos(AnsiLowerCase('Text'), AnsiLowerCase(Memo1.Text)) - 1;
    Memo1.SelLength := Length('Text');
    Memo1.SetFocus;
```

I used `AnsiLowerCase` so I can find text without the need for proper capitalization.

So, how can I select the second time "text" appears in the Memo?

Comment: Consider using `TRichEdit` instead. It has a `FindText()` method, which has a `StartPos` parameter, and a `stMatchCase` flag for controlling case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Offset` parameter of the [Pos](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Pos) function in order to avoid starting search from the beginning and skip the first occurrence.

> Locates a substring in a given string.
>
> The Pos method returns the index of the first occurence of Substr in
> Str, starting the search at Offset.
>
> This method returns zero if Substr is not found or Offset is invalid
> (for example, if Offset exceeds the String length or is less than 1).
>
> The Offset argument is optional. Offset is set to 1 by default, if no
> value for Offset is specified it takes the default value to start the
> search from the beginning.
>
> Notes:
>
> Pos uses one-based array indexing even in platforms where the
> strings are zero-based.
>
> Pos method is equivalent to System.StrUtils.PosEx.

**For example:**

[image: Picture displaying an example form with a memo, text edit and findnext button]

```
procedure SearchNext(AMemo : TMemo; const ATextToSearch : string; ACycle : Boolean = True);
var
  Offset : Integer;
begin
  //adjusting offset
  Offset := AMemo.SelStart + AMemo.SelLength + 1;
  if(Offset >= Length(AMemo.Text)) then
    Offset := 1;

  //searching
  Offset := Pos(AnsiLowerCase(ATextToSearch), AnsiLowerCase(AMemo.Text), Offset);
  if(Offset > 0) then
  begin
    //selecting found text
    AMemo.SelStart := Offset - 1;
    AMemo.SelLength := Length(ATextToSearch);
    AMemo.SetFocus;
  end else
  begin
    //recursion from the beginning
    if(ACycle and (AMemo.SelStart + AMemo.SelLength <> 0)) then
    begin
      AMemo.SelStart := 0;
      SearchNext(AMemo, ATextToSearch, True);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SearchNext(Memo1, Edit1.Text);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks to `ACicle` this is an endless recursion if `ATextToSearch` is not found.

Comment: Just note that the `Offset` parameter was added to `Pos()` in XE3. For earlier versions, use `PosEx()` instead.

Comment: Also, you probably mean `ACycle`, not `ACicle`. But AmigoJack's point is more important, of course.

Comment: You're all right, updated avoiding the ACycle mistake